# Multiple lines on link element "button"

Tags: html, css, hyperlink

I've been trying relentlessly to have multiple lines of text on my link buttons - but I just can't figure out how to do it! (I've seen it on other sites -- can't remember where though)

Here's the "button" (styled  element) that I'm trying to achieve the effect on: http://jsfiddle.net/TAvUF/1/

Everytime I try to achieve my goal I end up completely breaking up the button.

Could anyone advise me on how to do this? I've tried googling for some sort of tutorial but can't find one.

I'm sure that this is obvious and I'm overlooking something simple.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Just fiddled with your stuff on the link, and it looks like you just need to add:

```
display: block
```

to the .bluebutton styles. Then you can fiddle with the button dimensions or padding to get it the size you like. I tested with a `<br />` in the middle of the button text and it worked perfectly.

Comment: Or `inline-block`. But yeah, this is the answer. +1

Comment: If you're satisfied, please consider choosing it as the answer ;-)

Comment: I was always going to, was just waiting for the timer :)